# Dynamics AX 2012 Custom AIF document service read method returns empty array

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

After following the basic steps creating a custom document service with the AIF Document Service Wizard (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa856656.aspx). I tested it out with the WCF Test Client, but the read() method returns nothing. The Response entity returns an empty array.

I'm simply trying to retrieve rows from a table. I think I need to specify a value for the EntityKeyList, but I'm not sure what that would be. Perhaps Read is the wrong method.

Comment: I deleted the generated objects, and re-ran the AIF Document Service Wizard on my Query this time including all the CRUD methods available. Then with WCF Test Client I tried the find method. I expanded the QueryCriteria and provided a CriteriaElement of _null_ then Invoked the request, which returned all the rows from my table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the generated objects, and re-ran the AIF Document Service Wizard on my Query this time including all the CRUD methods available. Then with WCF Test Client I tried the find method. I expanded the QueryCriteria and provided a CriteriaElement of *null* then Invoked the request, which returned all the rows from my table!